# Element Number by Part

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to access the stress of some elements by part in an odb. Different parts are combined to one assembly so I need to know which range of element number refers to which part.

Do you know how to extract the element number from an Abaqus odb?
Thank you!

Philipp

Comment: You didn't mention Python, but I'm assuming that's what you're using. Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of your parts (element sets) by invoking

```
 for instanceName in odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].elementSets.keys():
    print instanceName
```

Then it is easy to obtain the element labels for each set. For example, the following prints the element labels of the element set 'DUMMY_MATERIAL'

```
 for v1 in part_instance.elements:
    if v1.sectionCategory.name == 'solid < DUMMY_MATERIAL >':
        print v1.label
```

Onnce you have the labels, you just need to choose an appropriate method to store the stresses at each integration point of each element.